# Sample invocations structured incorrectly:Google assistant

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I am trying to publish my Google Assistant project which I have integrated from DialogFlow and I keep getting an error

> For en:Sample invocations structured incorrectly

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure that the sample invocations that you've provided for the directory listing are set correctly. To review them:

- Select *Deploy*
- Choose *Directory information*
- Make sure you're looking at the *English* language tab, if you have multiple languages
- Expand the *Additional invocation phrases* section

Make sure the phrases are ones that will actually trigger your Action and make sense during invocation.

[image: visual representation of steps outlined]

If you are still having problems, you may wish to update your original question to show this information, or any other place  where you have provided the invocation phrase.